# stop menu from getting untidy when changing from relative positioning to absolute positioning

Tags: asp.net, css, positioning, html

I am looking for a jquery or javascript function which can convert relative positioning to absolute positioning without web page mess up,I have a very long and complicated menu which gets untidy when I change from relative to absolute and I can't figure out what to do,I will be really really thankfull for your help,give me the function or help me to stop menu from being untidy in absolute positioning,this is the menu code with #holder ul.sub li {position:absolute;}:

```
  #holder {width:750px; height:350px; position:relative; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-top:1px solid #da8; border-bottom:1px solid #da8; z-index:100;}
#holder table {border-collapse:collapse; margin:-1px;}
#holder ul {float:left; padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none;}
#holder ul.sub {margin-bottom:-4px;}
#menuOuter li a.lv1-a {background:blue; zoom:1;}
#menuOuter li a.lv1-a:hover {direction:ltr;}

#holder ul.sub {float:left;}
#holder ul.sub ul {position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:180px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a img {border-style: none;
        border-color: inherit;
        border-width: 0;
        display:block; position:absolute; left:-9999px; height:200px; width:737px;
    }

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li {display:block; float:left; width:150px; height:240px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a {margin-top:200px; width:110px; display:block; padding:0 20px; height:40px; line-height:40px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a1 {background:#e9a358;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a2 {background:#e9a358;}

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a5 {background:#b8826e;}

#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current a {margin-top:200px; height:40px;}
#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current ul {left:-9999px;}
#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current a img {left:-9999px;}

#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a {margin-top:200px; height:40px;}
#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current ul {left:-9999px;}
#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a img {left:-9999px;}

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover > a {margin-top:0; height:350px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover {margin-top:0; height:350px;}

#holder ul.sub li.current a {margin-top:0; height:350px;
        top: 14px;
        left: 28px;
    }
#holder ul.sub li.current a.a1 img {left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;}
#holder ul.sub li.current a.a2 img {left:-150px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

#holder ul.sub li.current a.a5 img {left:-600px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover a {margin-top:0; height:350px;}
#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul {left:0;}
#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px;}
#menuOuter li:hover ul.sub li.current:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}

#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover {margin-top:0; height:350px;}
#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul {left:0;}
#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px;}
#menuOuter a:hover ul.sub li.current a:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}


#holder ul.sub li {position:absolute;}

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul {left:0; width:130px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; font-size:11px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a1 img {left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a2 img {left:-150px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li:hover a.a5 img {left:-600px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul {left:0; width:130px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; font-size:11px;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a:hover ul li a:hover {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; text-decoration:underline;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a1:hover img {left:0; top:0; z-index:-1;}
#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a2:hover img {left:-150px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li a.a5:hover img {left:-600px; top:0; z-index:-1;}

#holder ul.sub li.current ul {left:0; width:130px;}
#holder ul.sub li.current ul li {float:left; height:15px; padding:0; margin:0;}
#holder ul.sub li.current ul li a {height:15px; line-height:15px; margin:0; padding:0 20px; font-size:11px;}

#holder ul.sub li span {display:block;position:absolute; top:240px; left:0; line-height:15px; width:130px; padding:10px; height:90px; z-index:-1; color:#000; text-decoration:none; font-size:11px;}
#holder ul.sub li.p1 span {background:#ffe398;}

#holder ul.sub li.p5 span {background:#f8c2ae;}

#holder ul.sub li.sub-li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 240px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and this is how it has to be:http://jsfiddle.net/MPdaX/

I have to change from relative positioning to absolute positioning because in relative positioning there will be lots of blank space end of web page,and I saw some functions also but none worked for me.thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a menu css or whole site css , For God sake dont believe in copy pasting try to write your own css its very easy and very help full

Comment: no this is css menu,no I saw it on a site and changed it as I needed it to be,I have made lots of changes to it,it hadn't any slideshow,now I am also trying to make it tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's a bit of html fixup needed. ( an extra double quote, a badly closed `<br/>` element, but ... well ... perhaps, instead of restructuring your whole thing to avoid the extra white-space at the bottom, you could just add

```
#holder {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to make it go away.

http://jsfiddle.net/hD6NY/